# Cant reduce margin for some reason

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a div and for some reason I cant reduce its margin.

HTML

```
<div class="activebombgame">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.activebombgame{
  height: 82vh;
  width: 5vw;
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
 }
```

[This is from google chrome developer tools(blue = div, orange = margin)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmeyK.png)

Whole source code: https://www.hastebin.com/tapodoyuke.xml

Comment: Use float:left;

Comment: Can you post the whole code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nisarg Shah,
You have added one extra closing div at the end, that's why your css is not working properly. Remove that extra closing div and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine see the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lp5rcg6/). Probably a surrounding tag is restricting the resize. Try something like taking ".activebomb" outside like

```
<div class="sorrounding"> 

</div>

<div class="activebombgame">

</div>
```

Comment: The only surrounding tag i have is container-fluid

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it's your `body` margin.  Many pages have one set by default.  See the test below for an example.  When you first run it, the body has a default margin.  Clicking the button will remove it and line your `div` up with the page edge.

```js
function change() {
    document.body.style.margin = "0px";
}
```

```css
.activebombgame{
  height: 82vh;
  width: 5vw;
  background: black;
  margin: 0px;
 }
 
 body {
   background-color: lightgray;
 }
 
 button {
   position: fixed;
   left: 40%;
   top: 20%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="activebombgame">

</div>

<button onclick='change();'>Remove Body Margin</button>
```

Comment: activebombgame still has margin check the google chrome developer tools.

Comment: @NisargShah What margin do you see?  Mine shows none.